# Automatically Increment application version on Worklight

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst

We are developing WL project using WL Enterprise ver 6.2.0.1, The build of the files (Native [ipa/apk] and Hybrid [.wlapp]) are done using ANT scripts.

Is there a way we can increment the application version inside (application-descriptor.xml) automatically during the build.?

Is there a script that we can use to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly different approach, but this sample (read "as-is") code should provide you enough to create your own ANT target to perform this:

```
<!-- =========================================================================== -->
<!-- Target: -update-build-number                                                -->
<!-- =========================================================================== -->
<target name="-update-build-number">
    <if>
        <isset property="${prop.buildNmber}" />
        <then>
            <property name="buildNumber" value="${prop.buildNmber}" />
        </then>
        <else>
            <tstamp>
                <format property="buildNumber" pattern="${prop.buildNumberPattern}" />
            </tstamp>
        </else>
    </if>

    <echo message="Setting application build Number : ${buildNumber}"   />

    <if>
        <istrue value="${prop.env.android}"   />
        <then>
            <echo message="Updating Android build number"   />
            <replaceregexp file="${appdir}/android/nativeResources/AndroidManifest.xml"
                           match='(android:versionCode=").*(" .*$)'
                           replace='\1${buildNumber}\2'
                           byline="true" />
        </then>
    </if>
    <if>
        <istrue value="${prop.env.ipad}"   />
        <then>
            <echo message="Updating IPad build number"   />
            <exec executable="/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy">
                <arg value="-c"/>
                  <arg value="Set CFBundleVersion ${buildNumber}" />
                  <arg value="${appdir}/ipad/native/${prop.iosNativePrefix}${prop.appName}Ipad-Info.plist"/>
            </exec>
        </then>
    </if>
    <if>
        <istrue value="${prop.env.iphone}"   />
        <then>
            <echo message="Updating IPhone build number"   />
            <exec executable="/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy">
                <arg value="-c"/>
                  <arg value="Set CFBundleVersion ${buildNumber}" />
                  <arg value="${appdir}/iphone/native/${prop.iosNativePrefix}${prop.appName}Iphone-Info.plist"/>
            </exec>
        </then>
    </if>
    <antcall target="-update-build-number-custom"  />
</target>
```

It requires the use of ant-contrib.